# Path to CSS, JavaScript and PHP files

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, path

I've made a page to add data into a table (MySQL). Everything works fine on my computer and on the server when I'm connected to the local network. But when I'm trying to access the application from home, it seems that the path to CSS and JS files is not right!
Here is how I use the link from office:
http://server.domain.eu/moni/call_ans.html

And here is what link I use from home:
https://server.domain.eu/moni/call_ans.html

Here is a part of my HTML code and how I include the JS and CSS file. I also use a PHP file, which is also linked wrong!

```
<head>
    <script src="jquery/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery/jquery-ui-sliderAccess.js"></script>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.min.css">
</head>

<script>
....
        $(document).ready(function() {

            $("#techForm").submit(function(e) {
             var url = "call_ans.php";
        });
    });
....
</script>
</head>
```

Comment: what is the full path for JS and CSS files?

Comment: use two <head>  might be problem and path may be

Comment: I don't think the 2 <head> is the problem. it is working as long as I'm at the office and I'm connected in the network

Comment: full path to js and css is \xampp\htdocs\jquery

Comment: on the server where is the location of you jquery folder in relationship to this file? is the jquery folder in the same folder? The same goes for the php file, to help you I think we need to better understand your directory structure. Also as a good practice, you should remove the duplicate head tags.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know the full path of your JS/CSS but assuming that https://server.domain.eu/moni is the site root, I'd suggest adding the following under `<head>` tags:

`<base href="https://server.domain.eu/moni">`

There's typo in your file it should be like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <base href="https://server.domain.eu/moni">
    <script src="jquery/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery/jquery-ui-sliderAccess.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.min.css">
</head>

<body>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function()
        {
            $("#techForm").submit(function(e)
            {
                var url = "call_ans.php";
            });
        });
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Best solution is to add direct `href` to specific scripts or add ./ to location of files. Adding base should help but I/m not using that solution usually:

```
 <script src="./jquery/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js"></script>
 <script src="./jquery/jquery-ui-sliderAccess.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="./jquery/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="./jquery/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.min.css">
```

Remember use dot slash to specific localization on server...

Comment: I cannot access the php file also! I think there is the same problem!

Comment: Add specific location for php file to have access to them. On serwer propably you have different access to files that on your pc.